# Javascript List Object can't add JSON? Node.JS, Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

```
router.get('/getAllMeals',function(req,res){    

    var allMeals = [];
    allMeals.push("foo");

    mealsRef.on("value",function(dataSnapShot){
        dataSnapShot.forEach(function(child){
            console.log(child.val());
            var oneMeal = child.val();
            allMeals.push(oneMeal);
        });
    }); 

    allMeals.forEach(function(obj){
        console.log(obj);
    });

    res.send(allMeals);
}); //RETRIEVE ALL
```

In the above code, I cannot add oneMeal which is a valid JSON object to the allMeals array I created. The result of console.log only shows the "foo" and also the length is 1.

Comment: I submitted a fix for your code, you knew there was an extra `});` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `mealsRef.on("value",function(dataSnapShot){` is a valid event; your `res.send(allMeals);` needs to be called in that callback.  Basically you are responding too soon.

Comment: A good read for every NodeJS developer, on asynchronous programming: [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Comment: A much better development pattern would be to use ES6 promises. Using Promises completely avoids "callback hell." If you are not using ES6 yet, there is a NodeJS polyfill available on NPM.  Here is a link to the polyfill. https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: Also, here is a link to the MDN site, which explains their implementation of Promises.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Just move res.send after datasnapshot.foreach inside callback , async hell is beating you.